# Run script only if screen is greater than 767

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I only want my script to run if the screen is greater than 767px, so I wrapped my script with

```
if($(window).width() > 767){
}
```

Here is my current script:

```
if($(window).width() > 767){
  $('header input').click(function() {
    $('#holiday-bg').css({
      'background-position': 'center center',
      'padding-bottom': '39%',
    });
  });
}
```

The script works when it is not wrapped, any ideas?

Comment: so ... if you `console.log($(window).width())` (just above your code, not in the console!!!) what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

> I only want my script to run if the screen is greater than 767px

you need to check the *window size* after the `click` event!

```
$( 'header input' ).click(function() {
    if( $( window ).width() > 767 )
    {
        $( '#holiday-bg' ).css({
           'background-position': 'center center',
           'padding-bottom': '39%',
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing "$" with "jQuery".

Comment: That is just an random answer completely unrelated to the question.